# But once we begin Vs But once we began

Tags: present-tense, past-simple, subjunctives, present-simple

> 1. But once we **began** to work hard, poverty **would** vanish.

What happens if we use **begin** instead of **begin** and **will** instead of **would**, means like below:

> 2. But once we **begin** to work hard, poverty **will** vanish.

What about other combinations like

> 3. once we **began** to work hard, poverty **will** vanish.
> 4. once we **begin** to work hard, poverty **would** vanish.

Which among the 4 sentences is correct and what is the difference in meaning between them, especially difference between sentence1 and sentence2 ?

Comment: (2) is a prediction about the future. (1) looks back to a time in the past when the speaker hoped that hard work was going to eliminate poverty. (3) and (4) don't make sense because the tenses are mixed up.

Comment: I don't think that 1 is legitimate either: It too has a conflict of tenses. Would require rewriting as; **But once we began to work hard, (it was hoped/expected etc) that poverty would vanish.** or **But once we began to work hard, poverty was expected to vanish.**

Comment: @KateBunting Is there any chance of sentence 1 to be subjunctive/hypothetical??

Comment: "Life in our new colony was difficult; we had little food the first year. But once we began to work hard, poverty would vanish - or so our leaders told us."